# In App Purchase Crashes App

Tags: objective-c, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an iOS App that I just submitted an update for. The development version of the app (simulator and my 4S) never crashed and it works just fine. The app got approved today as well as the IAP, but I realized this morning that the iAP was not "cleared for purchase". I just cleared it for purchase, but the app still crashes. The error the iPhone gives (running the app store version) gives the error:

`<Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'`

Here is the code where that happens:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:
(SKProductsResponse *)response
{
    NSArray *myProduct = response.products;
    //this line is where the error occurs
    noAdProduct = [myProduct objectAtIndex:0];
    if (![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"the id here"] boolValue]) {
        adCell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@", noAdProduct.price];
        adCell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        adCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        adCell.accessoryView = nil;
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

This happens while requesting a list of available products, which obviously returns the product in the simulator but not in the app. I just added a safeguard against this but I will need to submit it to the App Store again.

Does anyone know why the iAP is not showing up for the App Store version? Do I need to wait for the "cleared for sale" option to go to Apple's servers? Thanks!

Comment: Did you log `myProduc`? Are you registering your in app purchase identifiers?

Comment: The system works perfectly on the simulator, but on the phone, the array "response.products" comes empty. Is there a delay from when I check "cleared for purchase" in ITC and when apple's servers start acknowledging that? Also, what do you mean in the second question. In ITC it says "approved" on the iAP

Comment: `[[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:upgradeIdentifiers];` Did you register your in app purchases right there?

Comment: `SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                                     initWithProductIdentifiers: [NSSet setWithObject: @"the id"]];`

Comment: @NSAddict Here is the iTunes Connect screen for the in app purchase: http://cl.ly/image/1z3o2p1I0a3B

Comment: I'm not sure if you can test this in the sandbox. I think i have read somewhere, that you can only test it if you have submitted your binary.

Comment: They let you test iAPs in the sandbox now. They changed that I think. But now I have a submitted version that is crashing for people.

Comment: Maybe one of those will help you:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180782/updated-app-with-new-explicit-app-id-in-app-purchase-skproductsrequest-returns
http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1209939
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2120987?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `myProduct` array is empty. Why this happens is another question, but you should never call `objectAtIndex` without making sure the requested index exists.

```
if ([myProduct count] > 0)
    noAdProduct = [myProduct objectAtIndex:0];
else
   // Deal with the situation when the array is empty.
```